# Formatting a date with Mako templates

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

In my mako template I have:

```
<p>${item.addDate}</p>
```

It returns:

> 2012-12-27 19:50:00

but I would like to get:

> 27/12/2012 19:50

Have mako any nifty filters, format functions?

Comment: is `addDate` a string or a datetime object?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Why was your anser deleted?

Comment: I deleted it as yours was accepted.

Comment: I prefer your answer though, since it had more detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [google](https://github.com/ralsina/nikola/issues/101), `strftime` should do the job:

```
${post.date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

Also, according to google:

```
<%! from time import strftime as time %>
It is the ${"%d of %B" | time}
```